# Checking if a record exists before displaying in an angular form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a requirement to display 4 records out of an unknown number record on an Angular screen. In the sample data I am using there are 53 records so if I am only working with the sample data, there is no need if Data is present when I am loading the data.  However in the real world there could be 0 records that are returned.

I have come up with one way of potentially doing this, but what I have come up with feels like a brute force method rather then something that is elegant and modern. The relevant code that I have come up with is shown below.

snippet from .ts file

```
constructor(
    private repoService: UserApiService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<OrphansComponent>,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) {
    const fb = new FormBuilder;
    this.orphanForm = fb.group({
      naPartNo: null,
      altPartNo: null,
      partNo: null,
      rev: null,
      partStatusId: null,
      serialNo: null,
      lotNo: null,
      asBuiltQty: null,
      fltCrit: null,
      comments: null
    })
    this.orphanForm1 = fb.group({
      naPartNo1: null,
      altPartNo1: null,
      partNo1: null,
      rev1: null,
      partStatusId1: null,
      serialNo1: null,
      lotNo1: null,
      asBuiltQty1: null,
      fltCrit1: null,
      comments1: null,
    })
  }

  setData(){
    if(this.dataSource.data[0].fltCrit == 'Y'){
      this.dataSource.data[0].fltCrit = true;
    } else {
      this.dataSource.data[0].fltCrit = false;
    }
    const fb = new FormBuilder;
    if(this.dataSource.data[0] !== undefined){
      console.log('Item 0 in array');
      this.orphanForm = fb.group({
        naPartNo: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[0].naPartNo, disabled: false}),
        altPartNo: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[0].altPartNo, disabled: false}),
        partNo: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[0].partNo, disabled: false}),
        rev: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[0].asBuiltCl, disabled: false}),
        partStatusId: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[0].partStatusId, disabled: false}),
        serialNo: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[0].serialNo, disabled: false}),
        lotNo: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[0].lotNo, disabled: false}),
        asBuiltQty: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[0].asBuiltQty, disabled: false}),
        fltCrit: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[0].fltCrit, disabled: false}),
        comments: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[0].comments, disabled: false}),
      })
    };  
    if(this.dataSource.data[1] !== undefined){
      console.log('Item 1 in array');
      this.orphanForm1 = fb.group({
        naPartNo1: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[1].naPartNo, disabled: false}),
        altPartNo1: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[1].altPartNo, disabled: false}),
        partNo1: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[1].partNo, disabled: false}),
        rev1: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[1].asBuiltCl, disabled: false}),
        partStatusId1: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[1].partStatusId, disabled: false}),
        serialNo1: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[1].serialNo, disabled: false}),
        lotNo1: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[1].lotNo, disabled: false}),
        asBuiltQty1: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[1].asBuiltQty, disabled: false}),
        fltCrit1: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[1].fltCrit, disabled: false}),
        comments1: new FormControl({ value: this.dataSource.data[1].comments, disabled: false}),
      })
    };  
  }
```

snippet from .html file

```
    <div [formGroup]="orphanForm">
        <fieldset class="grid-item">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 80px;">
                    </td>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 160px;" colspan="2">
                        NA Part No
                    </td>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 160px;" colspan="2">
                        Alt Part No
                    </td>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 160px;" colspan="2">
                        Part No
                    </td>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 80px;">
                        Rev
                    </td>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 80px;">
                        Status
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 160px;" colspan="2">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 150px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="naPartNo"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 160px;" colspan="2">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 150px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="altPartNo"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 160px;" colspan="2">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 150px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="partNo"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 75px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="rev"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 75px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="partStatusId"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 80px;">
                        Serial No
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 75px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="serialNo"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 80px;">
                        Lot No
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 75px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="lotNo"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 80px;">
                        Qty
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 75px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="asBuiltQty"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 160px;" colspan="2">
                        <mat-checkbox formControlName="fltCrit" labelPosition="before" class="dataLabel">Flight Critical</mat-checkbox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 80px;">
                        Comments
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 640px;" colspan="8">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 630px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="comments"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div [formGroup]="orphanForm1">
        <fieldset class="grid-item">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 80px;">
                    </td>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 160px;" colspan="2">
                        NA Part No
                    </td>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 160px;" colspan="2">
                        Alt Part No
                    </td>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 160px;" colspan="2">
                        Part No
                    </td>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 80px;">
                        Rev
                    </td>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 80px;">
                        Status
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 160px;" colspan="2">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 150px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="naPartNo1"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 160px;" colspan="2">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 150px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="altPartNo1"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 160px;" colspan="2">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 150px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="partNo1"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 75px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="rev1"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 75px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="partStatusId1"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 80px;">
                        Serial No
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 75px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="serialNo1"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 80px;">
                        Lot No
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 75px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="lotNo1"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 80px;">
                        Qty
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 75px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="asBuiltQty1"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 160px;" colspan="2">
                        <mat-checkbox formControlName="fltCrit1" labelPosition="before" class="dataLabel">Flight Critical</mat-checkbox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dataLabel" style="width: 80px;">
                        Comments
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 640px;" colspan="8">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 630px;">
                            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="comments1"/>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

I am guessing there has to be better way to do this (i.e. a single form instead of multiple forms) but when I tried to put if statements inside the form group I started getting compile errors.  When I tried to have only only a single form only the last of the detail groups was populated.

I am hoping that someone can suggest a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a service with a method that take the data as input and return a FormArray.
FormGroup are for a fixed number of rows, and not very elegant.
[Here the documentation for Formarray](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms).
[Here the documentation about dynamic forms and how to create the service](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form)

Comment: Jean-Xavier, Thank you for your suggestion.  That might actually work if it wasn't for the first thing I mentioned in my question. The requirement calls for displaying a fixed number of rows on the screen even if there isn't data.  This actually is what is needed to match the application we are replatforming.  Based on the requirements we are trying to duplicate functionality from a 20+ year old application.  If the requirements were different I would do it this way.

Comment: Then forget about the FormArray, simply generate the FormGroup using a service. That way you can do it recursively: a method that take 1 row of data (potentially null) and return a GroupForm for that row. Then call the service in the component with the data received.

Comment: That is what I will do, thanks.  The requirements maybe don't call for the most elegant solution.